# Working code on JSFiddle, CodePen, but not on my computer

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a code, which is working fine here, on CodePen, on JSFiddle, but as soon as I copy and paste it onto Sublime Text and launch the website with Firefox, the drop-down menu doesn't work.

I have a network connection and I checked with a few browsers. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Move your `<script>` elements just before the closing `</body>` tag. Currently they are executed **before** the html has fully loaded, so there is no sub-menu to attach to.

Comment: Make sure your jQuery is being imported from the cdn

Comment: put your jQuery code inside `$( document ).ready(function() {});` to make sure the code runs after the page loads https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Possibly silly solution - is the js in a sibling file called script.js? And the css as style.css? Use the firefox "inspect element" to bring up the console, and see if anything fails to load

Comment: my bad, i'm sorry, it was simple, but I didn't saw it!
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or as SaymoinSam said :
I need to put my code inside

```
$( document ).ready(function() {});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is jQuery is not ready when your script is loaded.

These web development platforms like CodePen and JSFiddle usually load your script after every dependency has been loaded.

Move your `<script src="script.js"></script>` to just before you `</body>` tag and it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by the subarachnid user, change your .html file to the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Herbe Armée, Folle Béton</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <img class="titre" src="titre.png">

    <div class="wrapper-top">
        <div class="one">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class='sub-menu'>
                    <a href='#'>Expositions passées</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href='#'>Nom de l'expo 1</a></li>
                        <li> <a href='#'>Nom de l'expo 2</a></li>
                        <li> <a href='#'>Nom de l'expo 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="two">Instagram, Facebook, mail</div>
        <div class="three">Exposition en cours</div>
        <div class="four"></div>
        <div class="five">Artistes</div>
        <div class="six">Six</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper-bottom">
        <div class="seven">Sept</div>
        <div class="eight">Huit</div>
        <div class="nine">Neuf</div>
        <div class="ten">Dix</div>
        <div class="eleven">Onze</div>
        <div class="twelve">Crédits du site</div>
    </div>
    <div class="heure"><span id="cd"></span></div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tdh0z6qy/